# Google Analytics 4 - Explore section reports share with edit access

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I am using GA4 property to track my website data.
I have created a couple of reports from "Explore" option on the left side. (Funnel/ free form/ bar/ donut).

I want to share this report to other users - who are having the following access - Edit, Collaborate, Read and Analyze.

But when they view report shared by me - they are not able to edit any report property - for example not able to change the date on the top left, not able to change the metric value/ not able to change the dimension value (on left side panel).

How to **share editable exploration report in GA4** ? Is there an option of this? Should I change the access of the users?

Comment: Have a look at this - Share and export the exploration by Google If it help.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7579450?hl=en#:~:text=Click%20OK.-,Share%20and%20export%20the%20exploration,When,-you%20first

Comment: What's the point of a sharing feature for reports if other user's can't even change the date range? The people responsible for this part of GA4 should be fired, but instead they're probably making $300k+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some analysis found the answer.

If  other users wish to edit the report, including changing the date range,  they will have to duplicate the report so that they become the report owner.
And it worked !

Source : https://www.conversion-uplift.co.uk/create-an-exploration-report-in-google-analytics-4/